# How to get junction table name and keys from EF object context?

Tags: entity-framework

Was not able to find answers on this... I need to find the name of a junction table and its columns somewhere in the ObjectContext like I do for regular tables.

Comment: Please include your code!

Comment: There is no reason to include code because getting something from ObjectContext is a challenge. The way I take regular tables names doesn't work for junction tables.

Comment: In that case, I will try closing my eyes and imagining what you have tried so far.

Comment: @jcruz ObjectContext contains a huge value of complex metadata and I don't have any docs on how to pull something specific from it. When I needed to know regular tables names I just searched in SO for samples and got them. But this doesn't work for junction tables because they don't have corresponding EF entity types.

Comment: Have you tried using the `RelationshipManager` class?

Comment: Just googled and this didn't help.